# i have to move all files and folders from one list item to anthoer list item

Tags: office-365

for example
I have to move all files and folders from one list item to another list item

**ListitemName1:Jan Reports**

- Folder Name:Current Month

**ListitemName2:Old Reports**

- Folder Name: Previous Month

I have to all copy all files and folders to ListitemName1-Jan Reports(current month) to ListitemName2-Old Reports(previous Month)

Please provide any solution please help me.

Answer (score 1):

open both lists, both lists change the view to explorer view.

now you should have two folders open. 1 is the first list (from) and 2 is the second list (to)

copy or cut all files and folders (i would copy) from the first list folder (from) into the second list folder (to). Check to make sure everything is ok before removing the items from the first list just incase you didnt do anything correct!

goto the list page -> on the right hand side of the list at the top select the views drop down items and change it from the current view to 'explorer view' , this will then popup an explorer window just like on desktop that you can copy from your local machine to that location (copy/cut -> past or drag drop from one window(source) to the other window(target))

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2629108